# How to record the affliate ID of a person registered via meteor's accounts-ui and accounts-password

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

meteor's accounts-ui and accounts-password will work fine for my purposes except for one thing: when a user registers, I want to record who referred that user based on a query string parameter of `sponsor`, e.g. `www.mysite.com/?sponsor=bob`  ... is there a way to extract and record that information along with the newly registered user?

Comment: What router are you using? Iron:router, flow router or react router?

Answer (score 3):

The code you are referring to is called a route parameter (params).

Grabbing these params changes depending on what router you are using but the below is an example of doing it with `iron:router`

```
let code = Router.current().params.sponsor; //returns 'bob'

Accounts.createUser({ 
    email: 'test@test.com', 
    password: '123',  
    profile: { referral: code }
});
```

That's an example of storing the code in the user profile, but it may be wiser to create the user account on the server and immediately update the user document in the database so the code isn't stored on the user profile.

Comment: What router is standard with Meteor? What would I type at the command-line to install the "iron router"?

Comment: There isn't really a standard router. ```Iron:router``` was the main router for quite a while but then people seemed to start switching over to ```flow:router```. I personally use ```react-router``` because I use React for the view layer.

To add iron:router you just run ```meteor add iron:router``` in the command line. Guide found here: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/